# Executar uma Paginação PHP com JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, paginação

Fiz um script que importa imagens de um CMS próprio para o Wordpress e para não sobrecarregar o servidor e a maquina de importação esse sistema tem uma paginação que exibe 20 elementos por página:

http://localhost/sistema_importa/base_importat.php?pagina=160

Gostaria de saber se teria uma maneira de o jquery executar essa página e ao fim do carregamento dela o jquery mudar para a próxima página evitando que eu tenha que ta clicando em próximo direto e tornar o processo pouco mais rápido:

http://localhost/sistema_importa/base_importat.php?pagina=161

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o evento [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) no seu `window`, mais ou menos assim:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() ) {
       var url = document.URL;
       var pageNumber = url.split('=')[1];
       var newUrl = "http://localhost/sistema_importa/base_importat.php?pagina=" + pageNumber;

       $(location).attr('href', newUrl);
   }
});
```

Se você quer que a página seja recarregada quando o usuário chegar perto do final, use isso aqui:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 ) {
       var url = document.URL;
       var pageNumber = url.split('=')[1] + 1;
       var newUrl = "http://localhost/sistema_importa/base_importat.php?pagina=" + pageNumber;

       $(location).attr('href', newUrl);
   }
});
```

<sub>* Onde o `100` da condição representa o tamanho em pixels em relação ao final da página, você pode mudar pro número que desejar.</sub>

Mas eu não recomendo essa solução, aconselho você a utilizar algum plugin de [`Infinite Scroll/Lazy Loading`](http://jscroll.com/).

Comment: Muito obrigado @eduardo-silva Modifiquei sua ideia

`<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            //requisição ajax para selecionar postagens
      var url = document.URL;
       var pageNumber = url.split('=')[1];
       var numeroNovo = parseInt(pageNumber)-1;
       var newUrl = "http://localhost/sistema_importa/base_importat2.php?pagina=" + numeroNovo;

       $(location).attr('href', newUrl);
    }); // fim document ready
    </script>`